# How to custom search for text query in mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new in mongodb. I have following data as a JSON format in mongodb. I need to search the bookLabel or the shortLabel for the book and it should show me all the information about the book. For example: if I query for 'Cosmos' it'll show all the description about the book, like: bookLabel, writer, yearPublish, url. How can I do that in java? Need query, please help.

```
  "Class":"Science",
  "Description":[  
     {  
        "bookLabel":"Cosmos (Mass Market Paperback)",
        "shortLabel":"Cosmos",
        "writer":"Carl Sagan",
        "yearPublish":[  
           "2002"
        ],
        "url":"https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/55030.Cosmos"
     },
     {  
        "bookLabel":"The Immortal Life of Henrietta Lacks",
        "shortLabel":"Immortal Life",
        "writer":"Rebecca Skloot",
        "yearPublish":[  
           "2010, 2011"
        ],
        "url":"https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6493208-the-immortal-life-of-henrietta-lacks"
     }
  ],
  "Class":"History",
  "Description":[  
     {  
        "bookLabel":"The Rise and Fall of the Third Reich",
        "shortLabel":"Rise and Fall",
        "writer":"William L. Shirer",
        "yearPublish":[  
           "1960"
        ],
        "url":"https://www"
     }
  ]
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific. Which type of driver are you using for Java-MongoDB? Is your question how to filter the JSON files or how to query those BSON (Mongo works with a special type of format)?

Comment: What have you tried? This is also very easy to misinterpret and for you to get wrong in two approaches. Either use "regular expressions" to match over multiple fields with an `$or` condition, or index multiple fields with a "text" index and `$text` search option. Both have their pros and cons, and there is plenty of literature already on comparison. I suggest you work out what you are doing first.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use MongoDB's Text Search Capabilities. You'll have to create a `text index` on your collection for that.

First of all create a text index on your collection on fields `bookLabel` and `shortLabel`.

```
db.books.createIndex({ "Description.bookLabel" : "text", "Description.shortLabel" : "text" })
```

Note that this is done in the Mongo shell

Then

```
DBObject command = BasicDBObjectBuilder
                    .start("text", "books")
                    .append("search", "Cosmos")
                    .get();

CommandResult result =  db.command(command);
BasicDBList results = (BasicDBList) result.get("results");

for(Object o : results) {
  DBObject dbo = (DBObject) ((DBObject) o).get("obj");
  String id = (String) dbo.get("_ID");
  System.out.println(id);
}
```

Haven't really tested this. But just give it a try. Should work.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB Java Driver v3.2.2 you can do something like this:

```
FindIterable<Document> iterable = collection.find(Document.parse("{\"Description.shortLabel\": {$regex: \"Cosmos\"}"));
```

This returns all documents containing `Cosmos` in the `Description.shortLabel` nested field.  For an exact match, try this `{"Description.shortLabel": "Cosmos"}`.  Replace `shortLabel` with `bookLabel`to search the `bookLabel` field.  Then you can do `iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>())` on the returned documents.  To search both `bookLabel` and `shortLabel`, you can do a `$or{}`. My syntax could be wrong so check the MongoDB manual.  But this is the general idea.